# EF - Generate edmx from DB - foreign key naming

Tags: database, entity-framework, foreign-keys, edmx, ef-database-first

In EF, DB first, I generate my model from the DB.
My foreign keys get named randomly in the generated c# classes. 
It is very confusing.
Is there a way to force name the generated collection names (FK) or force EF to use the DB foreign key name ? 
Kindest Regards